# Recommendation on creating application testing server for unittest with GUI in Linux

Tags: python, unit-testing, user-interface

What is your recommendation on doing this

I have been testing my Linux application with LDTP using unittest so now I want to give users a web based GUI for:

1. Selecting Test
2. Running test
3. Viewing test status

I am pretty new to python and would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: my suggestions for the web server part: "[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a microframework for Python based on Werkzeug, Jinja 2 and good intentions." and for the UI, HTML, Javascript, JQuery ...

Comment: @cblab: comments are for asking for clarification. If you're going to answer the question you should do so as an answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, just I'm not sure being complete enough for a full answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a web service, you will need a web framework for the server-based code.

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a very convenient microframework for Python. Thanks to Werkzeug, it allows you to quickly and painlessly develop a web service, support RESTful routing, has a powerful debugger inside. And thanks to Jinja2, it supports templating for your webpages.

Now, for the UI part, you would have a look on the usual web kit, say HTML/CSS + Javascript ( probably JQuery)